# How to display a progress bar?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

There is much advice on the Internet about how to make a progress bar.

I made a userform, with label and frame and added code to the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 1 To 192
    Cells(i, 1) = "a"
    Label1.Width = i
Next i

End Sub
```

The progress bar is refreshed only after the end of execution of loop.

How to refresh a userform?

Comment: Put a `DoEvents` inside of your loop. It will slow it down, but the progress bar should work then.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked out really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoEvents` passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue (like screen updates). This is what you need if you are using a progress bar.

So put a `DoEvents` inside of your loop. It will slow it down, but the progress bar should work then.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  For i = 1 To 192
    Cells(i, 1) = "a"
    Label1.Width = i
    DoEvents
  Next i
End Sub
```

[VBA DoEvents Documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Comment: Thank you! can i add a new situation? I am doing the same thing with other procedure, i tried many things, but it did not work out. i have Usual sub in module, and i say "when sub (macro) is started, show userform, and after this row, change width of label1 to  10% (example), after that to 20%, and so on so on. in this situation nothing changing. How to do?

Comment: You dont set the width to a percent, you set it to a value between 1 and the total width that equals 100%.